# Iterm2 path color setting

Tags: macos, colors, terminal, iterm2

I used to be a ubuntu user but switched to Mac recently. I really want to configure the colorscheme of iterm2 to look act like ubuntu default terminal as much as possible.

The biggest problem is I can't configure the color of the current path. in Ubuntu, it is like [image]

However, in iterm2, the `bobby laptop name` and the `~/Documents` are the same color when I change the foreground. This is really annoying. It is really painful to look at your file path tangled with the machine name.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In iterm2, the bobby laptop name and the ~/Documents are the same color when you change the foreground.

You might adjust the Minimum Contrast to the maximum value.

Just adjust the Minimum Contrast to the middle value.

[image]

---

After some comments, I know you wanna change the PS1 part of bash.

Just use command `nano ~/.bash_profile` and paste the code to the end of the file:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Restart your terminal to see what happened.

You can adjust the color, the fonts, the text in terminal settings. Then you will get what you want.

For more information, you can search "OS X Terminal Colors".

Comment: I adjusted it to the middle but still the foreground color change affect everything.

Comment: Are you using zsh or some other shells on Ubantu and using bash on Mac? You may need to change bash to zsh or some other shells on Mac. $PS parameters on bash have only one color.

Comment: You can also make bash colorful. There are a lot of ways introduced in the related questions.

Comment: I am using bash on both Mac and ubuntu but somehow my ubuntu terminal can distinguish them. Anyways, thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, I know what you want. I will add the method to the answer.

Comment: Genius! Worked!

Comment: This does not work in macOS 10.15. I've posted a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029637/changing-username-hostname-and-path-color-in-iterm2

Answer (score 1):

1. Open bash_profile using `vi ~/.bash_profile`
2. Add below code:

---

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

3. Optional step, in case you want to hide username in path, replace last line with:

   `export PS1="\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "`
4. Close vi using `:wq` and run `source ~/.bash_profile`
5. In case the colorful path is still not visible verify the Minimum contrast and Cursor Boost setting as shown below.
   [image]