# Changing username, hostname, and path color in iterm2

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, iterm2

How can I change the username, hostname, and path color in iTerm2? I'm using the built-in Solarized colorscheme.

In Ubuntu, the same built-in colorscheme is highlighted like:
[image]

In iTerm2:
[image]

Current iTerm2 settings:
[image]

and
[image]

I've been playing around the settings but can't get it to work. I've also gone through numerous links, but those also settings don't work.

I'm on macOS 10.15.4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Default value of `$PS1`:

`%n@%m %1~ %#`

Updated value of `$PS1` from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59939561/13055097) (in the **Prompt Example** section):

`%(?.%F{green}.%F{green})%n@%m %1~ %# %f`

Added the below in my `.zshrc`:

```
export PS1='%(?.%F{green}.%F{green})%n@%m %1~ %# %f'
```

Edit:

The `PS1` below provides more options:

```
export PS1='%{%F{green}%}%n%{%f%}%{%F{white}%}@%{%f%}%{%F{green}%}%m %{%F{cyan}%}%1~ %{%f%}%%'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I am using now. Colours for prompt and `ls` command.

```
RED='\033[1;31m'
GREEN='\033[1;32m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
BLUE='\033[1;34m'
PURPLE='\033[1;35m'
CYAN='\033[1;36m'
WHITE='\033[1;37m'
RESET='\033[0m'

export PS1="$RED\u:$BLUE\w $GREEN\h$RESET$ "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxbxegedabagaced
```

Output:
[image: LSCOLORS and PS1]

Answer (score 2):

**For Zsh Users**
[image]

As per [this detailed discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689765/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-my-prompt-in-zsh-different-from-normal-text/59939561#59939561) on formatting/coloring your prompt:

To color your `hostname` and `username` **red**, and the `directory path` **yellow** like in the image above, add the following to your `~/.zshrc` :

```bash
# Load colors
autoload -U colors && colors
# Format your prompt using the colors
export PS1="%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[red]%}%m %{$fg[yellow]%}%~ %{$reset_color%}%% "
```

Supported Colors as per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689765/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-my-prompt-in-zsh-different-from-normal-text/59939561#59939561) are :
`red`, `blue`, `green`, `cyan`, `yellow`, `magenta`, `black`, & `white`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the colors on your terminal prompt to achieve that, this may be of help http://www.marinamele.com/2014/05/customize-colors-of-your-terminal-in-mac-os-x.html

Comment: The article shows PS1 profile for `bash`, and the values and formatting are different in `zsh`

Answer (score 0):

You should the PS1 environment variable in your bash / zsh profile file.

For example, if you're using bash, you could add the following line to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PS1='\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ '
```

A more detailed explanation of this env variable can be found 
[here](https://ss64.com/osx/syntax-prompt.html)